# Displaying the value of a specific row/column in a matrix channel field

Tags: matrix, fields

I am attempting to make a dynamic table for some of my products in ExpressionEngine.

Right now I have the table data set up as a matrix channel field type. Each of my products has 3 variations with 8 columns of specs for each variation. My question is, how can I output a specific row in a column on the front-end.

My channel fields are cell_1 - cell_8. If I put {cell_1} into a `<th>` it generates 3 tables with each table using a different row from that column.

Is it possible to output a specific row from a matrix column?

Thanks!

Here's an example of my current code:

```
<tr>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>{cell_1} (want to call cell 1 row 1 here)</th>
    <th>{cell_1} (want to call cell 1 row 2 here)</th>
    <th>{cell_1} (want to call cell 1 row 3 here)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Color</td>
    <td>{cell_2} (want to call cell 2 row 1 here)</td>
    <td>{cell_2} (want to call cell 2 row 2 here)</td>
    <td>{cell_2} (want to call cell 2 row 3 here)</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix has a "row_count" variable you could use, something like this:

```
{matrix_field}
  {if row_count == "1"}
    First row content
  {if:else}
    Remaining row content
  {/if}
{/matrix_field}
```